# Access Code - mantantory fields in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the following vba code in my form.

```
Private Sub imgCustomer_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplashScreen"
Exit_This_Sub:
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

My problem is that the form contains textbox which must not left empty. If for example Surname and Name fields must have a value and the user only fill the Surname and press the imgCustomer_Click, the database will continue without showing a error to fill up the empty fields. Any ideas?

ps: Can I use a vba so it will automatically fill the field with a value, instead?

Comment: You are saving a form to your database. If you define the fiels in the database as NOT NULL, then the database will not allow these fields to stay empty and will complain upon the save in `DoCmd.Close`

Comment: As Paul said, can set field in table as required then let Access nag users to do input. If you want a custom message then use VBA code in form BeforeUpdate event to do the validation. As a sidenote, be aware the acSaveYes parameter has nothing to do with saving the record, it is to save the form design changes. Record is saved when 1. closing table/query/form, or 2. moving to another record, or 3. run code `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to validate the required fields and proceed when validation is successful.

```
Private Function FormValidated() As Boolean
    With Me
        If IsNull(.FirstControlName.Value) Then Exit Function
        If IsNull(.SecondControlName.Value) Then Exit Function
        'additional controls...
    End With

    FormValidated = True
End Function
```

You can then call it in your procedure:

```
Private Sub imgCustomer_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

        If Not FormValidated Then
            MsgBox "Validation failed.", vbExclamation
            GoTo Exit_This_Sub
        End If

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplashScreen"

Exit_This_Sub:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

If this is a bound form, you need to cancel the auto-update and save the record only when validation is successful.

```
Option Explicit

'Set a flag for manual update
Private mIsUserUpdate As Boolean 'Flag

'Cancel auto-update
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not mIsUserUpdate Then Cancel = True
End Sub

'Save
Private Sub imgCustomer_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

        If Not FormValidated Then
            MsgBox "Validation failed.", vbExclamation
            GoTo Exit_This_Sub
        End If

        mIsUserUpdate = True  'flag ON
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCustomer", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplashScreen"

Exit_This_Sub:
    mIsUserUpdate = False   'Flag OFF
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub

'Validation
Private Function FormValidated() As Boolean
    With Me
        If IsNull(.FirstControlName.Value) Then Exit Function
        If IsNull(.SecondControlName.Value) Then Exit Function
        'additional controls...
    End With

    FormValidated = True
End Function
```